# Installing an APK results in a parse error

Tags: android, apk

I created an `app-debug.apk` file in `/sdcard/Download`

I have this code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sdcard/Download/" + "app-debug.apk")),
    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Parse error
>
> There was a problem parsing the package.

How can I modify it programmatically without getting this error?

Comment: this message mean that the apk is corrupted. you can't do much about it unless if its yours, then make sure its not corrupted!

Comment: @k0sh  apk is corrupted ? but my apk is simply.   only showing update text

Comment: maybe not built probably? why don't you try and build again?

Comment: Have you declared the manifest permission for writing in sd card.<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Have you enabled installing applications from unknown sources? The code is fine and shouldn't have anything to do with your error. If it had a chance to execute at all, there would be no parse error.

Comment: I check unknown source and add write_external_storage

Comment: It could be Your Android smartphone OS version or the hardware is not compatible with the app. or  if you have made changes to the app’s manifest file like changing the Android version.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787412/first-try-parse-error-but-second-try-success-install-on-android   my questionm

Comment: I would suggest to access the download folder via `new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` instead of the hard-coded location, because it is not in the same location on every device. The parse error could be a result of the app not finding the apk. So name and location of the apk have to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

For Android N and above you should use `FileProvider` like this :

```
        Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
        intent.setData(apkUri);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml :

```
    <application ...>
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
    </application>
```

Then create file named `provider_paths.xml` under `res/xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Don't forget to add permission in manifest also:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Comment: `setFlag()` causes **security exception** instead using `addFlag` worked for me.