# first try parse error. but second try success install on android

Tags: android

I want

First , write my server url 
2. download apk
3. install apk

when I install apk

parse error message .
but retry install    , success install apk.

In summary , first try install apk.  parse error message 
after try . success install apk.

```
 String url = "https://myserver/.apk ";
            File apkFile = new File("/sdcard/Download/openapk.apk");

            Uri mUri = Uri.parse(url);
            DownloadManager.Request r = new DownloadManager.Request(mUri);
            r.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "openapk.apk");
            r.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(r);  



            Uri apkUri = Uri.fromFile(apkFile);
            Intent webIntent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            webIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            webIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(webIntent);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing an APK results in a parse error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783585/installing-an-apk-results-in-a-parse-error)

Answer (score 0):

Download Manager works asynchronously so you cannot just try to install your APK instantly right after you called `dm.enqueue()` because your code is not waiting there but, as name tells, enqueues the download and returns control to your code while download goes on on separate worker.

You must wait for Download Manager to complete and then try to install your app. Download Manager broadcasts `ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` intent action when download is completed, so you just need to wait for it and then act.

Docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html